# PHP Array values to unique keys

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an associative array that is built from a MYSQL query result. It has 190 keys which are made up of 10 unique 'name' and 19 unique 'display_name' (2B, 3B, HR, RBI, HR etc), with each 'name' and 'display_name' combination having a 'value'.

```
    array (size=190)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Name 1' (length=17)
      'display_name' => string '2B' (length=2)
      'value' => string '10' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Name 2' (length=20)
      'display_name' => string '2B' (length=2)
      'value' => string '7' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Name 3' (length=18)
      'display_name' => string '2B' (length=2)
      'value' => string '5' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Name 4' (length=19)
      'display_name' => string '2B' (length=2)
      'value' => string '3' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Name 5' (length=11)
      'display_name' => string '2B' (length=2)
      'value' => string '4' (length=1)
```

I would like to build array that has the unique 'display_name' as keys along with the 'name' as a key and the 'value' associated with that.  In other words, if you were visualize this as a table, currently it looks like:

```
name  :   display name :  value
name1     2B              10
name2     2B              7
name3     2B              5
name4     2B              3
name5     2B              4
```

I would like it to look like:

```
name   :  2B   :  3B  :  RBI  :  HR
name1     10      5      7       10
name2     8       6      5       9
name3     9       4      3       5
name4     2       1      1       1
name5     6       2      2       8
```

I know I can do this in MYSQL but I would like to know the solution in PHP.  I have tried many different things and referenced (among many others):
[Transposing multidimensional arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)

MYSQL similar solution:
[Transpose Rows to Headers in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619784/transpose-rows-to-headers-in-mysql)

The closest that I can get to is this, but it does get me the unique 'display_name' values as keys, rather $fieldHash['display_name'] all 190 values.

```
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
$row [] = $arr;
foreach($row as $resultArray){
foreach ( $resultArray as $key=>$val ){
$fieldHash[$key][] = $val; 
}
}
}
```

In this instance, I know the data model but in the future I would like to be dynamic for any number of 'display_name'.

If it's helpful, here is the MYSQL Query:

```
$query = "SELECT teaminfo.name, league_stat_categories.display_name, team_points_season.value
FROM team_points_season, teaminfo, league_stat_categories 
WHERE team_points_season.league_key = '$league_key' AND team_points_season.team_key = teaminfo.team_key AND team_points_season.league_key = league_stat_categories.league_key 
AND team_points_season.stat_id = league_stat_categories.stat_id
GROUP BY league_stat_categories.display_name, team_points_season.team_key";
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//recieved_arr - your array from example

$new_arr=array();
foreach($recieved_arr as $arr){
   // $arr['name']; $arr['display_name']; $arr['value']; - your values for current element
   $name = $arr['name'];
   $new_arr[$name]['display_name'] = $arr['display_name'];
   $new_arr[$name]['value'] = $arr['value'];

}
```

Comment: When I use this solution for a larger set of data (e.g. 6000 rows), I receive a Fatal Error "Allowed memory size".  I am aware that I can increase this parameter in my script, however is there a more scalable solution?  I am also aware that my original question was for 190 rows and I may have materially changed the question.