# how to transform rows into columns from select result

Tags: mysql

I have this select result after execute sql query

```
+-----------+-------+-----------+
| COL1      | COL2  | COL3      |
+-----------+-------+-----------+
| project1  | FAM1  | 1250.251  |
| project1  | FAM2  | 2145.325  |
| project2  | FAM1  | 2146.152  |
| project2  | FAM2  | NULL      |
| project3  | FAM1  | NULL      |
| project3  | FAM2  | 1248.002  |
| project4  | FAM1  | NULL      |
| project4  | FAM2  | NULL      |
| project5  | FAM1  | 3201.684  |
| project5  | FAM2  | 7325.981  |
```

I want to transform to this format

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| COL1      | FAM1      | FAM2        |COL3       |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| project1  | 1250.251  | 2145.325    | 3395.576  |
| project2  | 2146.152  | 0.0         | 2146.152  |
| project3  | 0.0       | 1248.002    | 1248.002  |
| project4  | 0.0       | 0.0         | 0.0       |
| project5  | 3201.684  | 7325.981    | 10527.665 |
```

transform COL2 to multiple colomn with our redundancy and COL3 is the sum of FAM1 & FAM2

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619784/transpose-rows-to-headers-in-mysql

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).